# Assembly program not working

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

I'm having problems with my program in assembly. The program is supposed to do the following:

Say "Welcome" > wait one second > Say "Press 2 to(Str_roll_1) roll(Str_roll_2)" > If 2 is pressed, start rolling the dice untill the key is released > show value and store it > go back to "Press 2 to roll" > repeat

But for some reason, that I can't wrap my head around, the code pretty much skips the "roll_dice" part and goes around in a loop showing "Rolling..." > "Value: 0" > "Rolling..." > "Value: 0" > ... and so forth

I'm using a arduino leonardo circuit board if that's any help. I don't know if that's enough information, but if you need more info just ask. Thanks :)

Main part of the code: (I hope the subroutines I haven't included are pretty self-explanatory)

```
main: 
PRINTSTRING Str_welcome
RCALL delay_1_s
RCALL lcd_clear_display

PRINTSTRING Str_roll_1
LDI RVAL, 0xC0
RCALL lcd_write_instr
PRINTSTRING Str_roll_2

loop:
CALL read_keyboard
LDI R25, 0x04
CP R25, RVAL
BREQ two

RJMP loop

two:
RCALL lcd_clear_display
PRINTSTRING Str_rolling
RCALL delay_1_s
RCALL roll_dice
RCALL store_stat
RCALL lcd_clear_display
PRINTSTRING Str_value
SUBI R24, -48
RCALL lcd_write_chr
RCALL delay_1_s

RJMP cont

cont:
RCALL lcd_clear_display
PRINTSTRING Str_roll_1
LDI RVAL, 0xC0
RCALL lcd_write_instr
PRINTSTRING Str_roll_2
RJMP loop

roll_dice:
    LDI R16, 6
test:   
    NOP
    NOP
    RCALL read_keyboard
    CPI RVAL, 0x04
    BREQ roll
    RET
roll:   
    DEC R16
    BREQ roll_dice
    RJMP test
```

Keyboard file //////////

```
map_table: .DB "147*2580369#"

read_keyboard:
LDI R18, 0      ; reset counter
LDI ZH, high(map_table <<1) ;Initialize Z pointer
LDI ZL, low(map_table <<1)
ADD ZL, RVAL ;Add index
LDI RVAL, 0x00
ADC ZH, RVAL ;Add 0 to catch Carry, if present
LPM RVAL, Z

scan_key:
MOV R19, R18
LSL R19
LSL R19
LSL R19
LSL R19
OUT PORTB, R19      ; set column and row
```

*insert 22 NOP lines here*

```
SBIC PINE, 6
RJMP return_key_val
INC R18
CPI R18, 12
BRNE scan_key
LDI R18, NO_KEY     ; no key was pressed!

return_key_val:
MOV RVAL, R18
RET
```

Comment: Use a debugger/simulator to figure out the problem yourself. Also, at the very least, post code for `read_keyboard`. We can't tell if it maybe changes `R16` or how it even sets `RVAL`. Make sure keys are properly debounced.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Added the code from the keyboard file

Comment: The mapping part of `read_keyboard` doesn't make any sense to me. It does stuff based on the previous value of `RVAL` which then gets overwritten anyway. The `scan_key` loop is also strange. Even if all of that somehow works, I don't see any debouncing which may cause your problem with real hardware.

Comment: The fact that there's something wierd with the read_keyboard is really annoying since my teacher created it... I'm gonna talk with him about that when I get the chance.

I'm going to check the buttons for contact bounce when I get a chance.

Comment: I moved the GND closer to the keyboard instead of having it go through several cables first, this solved the issue (where it looped between "Rolling..." and "Value: 0"). So now it stays on Rolling... until I release the key, but the problem with it showing "Value: 0" instead of actually showing a number between 1-6 is still there.

Comment: There seems to be some key bounce. But I don't really know what to do about it

Comment: I managed to fix everything. Everything works as intended now. Thanks to all of you for your feedback and suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that your problem isn't software, but hardware.  I bet if you put an oscilloscope on the key you'll see it has contact bounce. The switch will momentarily close, but then re-open and re close several times before becoming a stable value.

That means that since you leave your delay loop as soon as the first bounce happens, it appears that it never happens (though it did *very briefly*). If you call read_keyboard and turn on a pin (or the debugging LED) if key two is active, and turn it off if key 2 is inactive, you'll see that later key 2 is working, but you won't see the quick  blips as it changes state.  contact bounce is typically on the order of milliseconds, but can be longer on exceedingly crappy switches.

Usually the best solution to this is to continually monitor the state of the buttons in a timer, and only update a global state variable once the pin has settled.  Your main code will then only look at state that's properly filtered and stable.  There are hardware ways to do this as well, so the exact solution you choose is an engineering concern that depends on the whole system design

Comment: @Isac Oskarsson To give a little perspective on how much time you might need based on this answer, where you have 22 nop's, you'd need 80,000 for a 5 ms delay @ 16 Mhz.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the development process to be a lot less complicated by doing something like this, as assembly can evolve into spaghetti code real easy.

```
; ============================================================================================
; This pair of complimentary routines controls function of watchdog timer.

;   ENTER:  R24 = Bits 5 & 2:0 deliniate prescaler value WDP3:0 (11-2 pg 55)
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    .equ    WDT_Change_Enable = (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDE)

  WDT_Enable:
        in      R20, SREG               ; So I flag bit 7 will be returned in original state.

    ; During this process, we do not want interrupts or an inadvertant timeout of WDT.

        cli                             ; Disable interrupts
        wdr                             ; To be sure we have at least 16ms to setup

  WDT_Set:
        lds     R25, WDTCSR             ; 11.9.2 pg 54 Control Register
        sbr     R25, WDT_Change_Enable
        sts     WDTCSR, R25             ; Begin timmed sequence
        sts     WDTCSR, R24             ; Write desired parameters

    ; A change to watchdog can happen anywhere, so if global interrupts are already
    ; disabled, we do not want to change the flags state.

        out     SREG, R20               ; In order to not modify "I" flag.
        ret

; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  WDT_Disable:
        in      R20, SREG               ; See comments @ WDT_Enable
        cli
        wdr

    ; See note a bottom of page 52 ATMEL 8271I-AVR-10/2014

        in      R25, MCUSR              ; 7.3.1 pg 11
        cbr     R25, WDRF               ; Clear watchdog reset bit
        out     MCUSR, R25

    ; Reset watchdog enable, but retain prescaler.

        lds     R24, WDTCSR
        cbr     R24, RSET               ; Clear bit so watchdog will be disabled.
        rjmp    WDT_Set
```

This does two things. (1) It fortifies a concept as once you've written the comment, double check that is what the code will do and (2) others reading won't have to guess what any part is doing and why.

**Jester wrote:**

> It doesn't make any sense to me.

I'm pretty sure he doesn't mean to imply your code is nonsensical, but rather what is intuitive to you is not to us. I'm willing to bet, if you spend much more time documenting, the problem is going to jump right out at you and if not, then for those you ask help of, it's going to be a lot easier to understand your logic.

You may be right, but I've found too, to assume what you haven't included doesn't have a problem, be presumptuous.